# how to create a new joomla component for integrating the google map api

Tags: joomla

how to create a new joomla component for integrating  the google map api

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else you could need that wouldn't be covered by http://tech.reumer.net/google-maps/documentation-of-plugin-googlemap/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some great tutorials out there on how to extend Joomla, I found this one :

http://www.vojtechovsky.net/joomla/component-helloworld-tutorial-guide-en.html

after googling 'joomla create component'

But why reinvent the wheel?  Most of the Google Maps extensions you can find on extensions.joomla.org are open source.

You could just download one, and edit the code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Give the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) a try. It will generate all the files you need, then you just need to paste in the Google maps code.